# Wordpress Single Sign On Client free plugin to authenticate users against external OAuth2 server

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I'm working on a project for a client who has their own OAuth2 SSO authentication server they use on multiple different apps.

Previously their Wordpress website was password-protected (in order to access it they used the Password Protected plugin which hid everything on the website until the user input one specific shared password.

Now they want their Wordpress website to:

- Immediately redirect to their (non-wordpress) SSO login website
- After logging in (or detecting that the user is already logged in) redirect back to the Wordpress site. I already have all the requirements - client ID, realm, secret, I am on the whitelist of the SSO server
- There are no requirements to sign REST requests or anything. All the SSO needs is to restrict the data on the wordpress site unless the user is already logged in on their server, or redirect them to the server if they are not logged in and after logging in redirect them back with the redirect-uri parameter.

However, I am having trouble finding the right plugin,since there is no budget fora paid plugin. I have tried miniOrange but in order to restrict all access to users who are not logged in I'd have to use the paid version. Oauth0 is also paid.

Is there any other plugin or a set of plugins that would help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone discovered this post, I managed to finish it myself. I used [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth-client-for-user-authentication/) but had to manually rewrite it quite a lot, changing the conditions on when to call the authentication endpoint (call it on init rather than on url route parameter change), had to write new code for calling reshresh token endpoint and logout endpoint and all sorts of other stuff.

Sadly, i can't publish the newly edited plugin, since my client wouldn't allow it. The takeaway from this is that if you want SSO against an external identity provider in such a way that without being logged in through your SSO you can't view the page, it's difficult and you'd either have to pay money for an expensive plugin or extend an existing plugin, spending days figuring out how to do it.

Comment: Please be careful with the linked WordPress plugin, as it contains a critical auth bypass vulnerability: https://lana.codes/lanavdb/85e045c9-1d56-4b58-9088-bac0aa3a1173

Answer (score 0):

Was working on something similar way back. It is true that for most of the plugins we need to pay. I too have tried miniorange and the other [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth-client-for-user-authentication/) you have mentioned. The use case which you are referring to, I have done some manual changes from my side to achieve it and never got the solution I was looking for. After some research, I found out that this Page and Post restriction plugin by miniorange itself along with the [SSO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-and-post-restriction/) can be used to restrict all access to users who are not logged in if I am not wrong about it, you can give it a try yourself.